# The symmetric matrix A below has distinct eigenvalues −3, −1 and 2. Find an orthogonal matrix P and a diagonal matrix D such that $P^TAP=D$

Tags: linear-algebra

The symmetric matrix A below has distinct eigenvalues −3, −1 and 2. Find an orthogonal matrix P and a diagonal matrix D such that $P^TAP=D$

\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 &   1 \\
-2 & -1 &  -1\\
1 & -1 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now, I understand how to find the diagonal matrix. I know what is an orthogonal matrix. I am simply confused how can I find the orthogonal matrix out of this?

Comment: the length of a vector is a real number, often involving a square root. Dividing the entries of a vector by its (original) length gives a vector of length one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find an eigenvector corresponding to each of the eigenvalues by solving $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

Since the eigenvalues are all distinct, these eigenvectors will be orthogonal to each other.

Then you can divide each eigenvector by its length to get an orthonormal set of eigenvectors, and then take P to be the matrix with these vectors as its columns (in some order).